# Conflicts when source setup.bash

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I wrote an global planner for my turtlebot.
But when I tried to source my .bashrc, only one setup.bash can work.
When I `source ~/turtlebot/devel/setup.bash`,
I can use simulator or navigation .
But I need to load my own planner plugin,
so I `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`,
Then  I can see the plugin.
But I can not use anything about turtlebot now.
It seems that `source ~/turtlebot/devel/setup.bash` is cancelled.
If I `source ~/turtlebot/devel/setup.bash` again,
I can use turtlebot but I can not see my plugin,
`source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`stopped working.
Can anybody help me with this?
For convenience, I usually put all such things in .bashrc file.
But it seems that only one setup.bash can work at a time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199783/conflicts-when-source-setup.bash/) by [Tixiao](https://answers.ros.org/users/20747/tixiao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 130 on 2014-12-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-18**:
I would suggest copying the whole turtlebot package into your catin_ws/src and only sourcing catin_ws/devel/setup.bash will not produce any conflicts. I have been tweaking a lot of turtlebot packages this way and had no issues so far. Try it.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-12-19**:
Especially take care of section 3.3 of the tutorial @Thomas D linked.

**Comment by [Murilo F. M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2499/murilo-f.-m./) on 2014-12-22**:
Also, [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/190536/catkin-fails-to-chain-workspaces/#190588) and [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/195877/how-to-source-only-select-workspaces/#195982) are closely related to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like issues with workspace overlaying (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying). You should be able to do what you want, I'm just not sure exactly how without diving into it more. Hopefully that link gets you in the right direction.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2014-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3